# Is Lucifer really Satan or has history been unfair to St. Lucifer of Cagliari?

Tags: isaiah, hebrew-bible, latin-vulgate

It seems to me that Lucifer is not the name of Satan but a result of faulty translation into the Vulgate at Isa 14:12. Is there sufficient reason to back this claim or am I mistaken?

Comment: Greetings Brian - I suggest doing a forum search for “Isaiah 14:12”. I’m sure the results will provide some understanding for what you’re asking

Comment: Thanks Dave. Will do so.

Comment: This question is very much on-topic. We discussed it in class with [John Walton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_H._Walton).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Brian. It would be helpful if you could provide some historic info on this person called St. Lucifer of Cagliari. Until you do, your question can only comprise the first four words, and it lacks any sign of research. Further, you really should quote the words of the Vulgate at Isa.14:12. Then you might get more of a response.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the Latin Vulgate and its translation of Isa 14:12; but this question is slightly more involved that it first appears.

It will come as a shock to some that the name “Lucifer” does not occur in the Hebrew Bible at all; it is in neither the Hebrew text nor the Greek text of the LXX.  It is an unfortunate translation of the KJV (and of John Wycliffe) in Isa 14:12 which most modern versions do not have.  What are the facts?

- The Hebrew word in Isa 14:12 is הֵילֵל (helel - a hapex legamenon), meaning, “shining one”, from the root word, “halal” meaning, “to shine”.  The word was used to describe Venus, the morning (or evening) star (actually a planet!), but which easily outshines Sirius.  The complete phrase in the Hebrew is “helel ben-shachar” meaning “Venus, son of the morning”, or, “Morning star, son of the morning”.
- The Septuagint (in Greek) translated the word, “heosphoros” which means, “Morning star”.  This translation is correct.
- The Latin Vulgate (Jerome 400 AD) translated the word, “lucifer” meaning “light bearer”.  This translation is correct – for Latin.

It is apparent that the KJV translators struggled with the Hebrew and transliterated the Latin word instead of translating it.  John Wycliffe (who translated from the Latin and knew no Greek or Hebrew) also appears to have been flummoxed as he left the word untranslated.  They appear to ignore the fact that the same word appears elsewhere in the Latin Bible describing other things.  (2 Peter 1:19, Job 11:17, 38:32, Ps 110:3)

It is only in the later English Christian tradition that “Lucifer” became a proper noun referring to the Devil before his fall, which the Hebrew does not do.

Note the comments of Ellicott on Isa 14:12 -

> (12) How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the
> morning!—The word for Lucifer is, literally, the shining one, the
> planet Venus, the morning star, the son of the dawn, as the symbol of
> the Babylonian power, which was so closely identified with astrolatry.
> “Lucifer” etymologically gives the same meaning, and is used by Latin
> poets (Tibull. i., 10, 62) for Venus, as an equivalent for the
> phôsphoros of the Greeks.

See also Barnes and Benson in this location:  https://biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/14-12.htm

**What does Isa 14;12 refer to?**

Isa 14 is part of a larger passage, Isa 13:1 - Isa 14:27 - a prophecy about the king of Babylon.  This much is not controversial.

However, many Christians have understood a few verses (Isa 14:12-15) in this prophecy about the king of Babylon as describing the origin and fall of Satan.  That is, such people interpret Isa 14:12-15 about the king of Babylon with **a secondary meaning** as applying to Satan.  For example, see the commentary by Ellicott

This is disputed by some and its not the subject of this question to debate or even discuss these understandings here; in any case, that discussion would venture into theology.  I will simply quote Ellicott's further comment on Isa 14:12 about the origin of the name "Lucifer" as a proper name in English:

> The use of the word [Lucifer], however, in mediæval Latin as a name of
> Satan, whose fall was supposed to be shadowed forth in this and the
> following verse, makes its selection here singularly unfortunate. Few
> English readers realise the fact that it is the king of Babylon, and
> not the devil, who is addressed as Lucifer. While this has been the
> history of the Latin word, its Greek and English equivalents have
> risen to a higher place, and the “morning star” has become a name of
> the Christ (Revelation 22:16).

Finally, as if to summarize the situation, let me quote the comments of Albert Barnes in Isa 14;12 about "Lucifer".

> How art thou fallen from heaven - A new image is presented here. It is
> that of the bright morning star; and a comparison of the once
> magnificent monarch with that beautiful star. He is now exhibited as
> having fallen from his place in the east to the earth. His glory is
> dimmed; his brightness quenched. Nothing can be more poetic and
> beautiful than a comparison of a magnificent monarch with the bright
> morning star! Nothing more striking in representing his death, than
> the idea of that star falling to the earth! Lucifer - Margin,
> 'Day-star' (הילל hēylēl, from הלל hâlal, "to shine"). The word in
> Hebrew occurs as a noun nowhere else. In two other places Ezekiel
> 21:12; Zechariah 11:2, it is used as a verb in the imperative mood of
> Hiphil, and is translated 'howl' from the verb ילל yālal, "to howl"
> or "cry." Gesenius and Rosenmuller suppose that it should be so
> rendered here. So Noyes renders it, 'Howl, son of the morning!' But
> the common translation seems to be preferable. The Septuagint renders
> it, Ἑωσφόρος Heōsphoros, and the Vulgate, 'Lucifer, the morning
> star.' The Chaldee, 'How art thou fallen from high, who wert splendid
> among the sons of men.' There can be no doubt that the object in the
> eve of the prophet was the bright morning star; and his design was to
> compare this magnificent oriental monarch with that. The comparison of
> a monarch with the sun, or the other heavenly bodies, is common in the
> Scriptures.
>
> Son of the morning - This is a Hebraism (see the note at Matthew 1:1),
> and signifies that that bright star is, as it were, the production, or
> the offspring of morning; or that it belongs to the morning. The word
> 'son' often thus denotes possession, or that one thing belongs to
> another. The same star in one place represents the Son of God himself;
> Revelation 21:16 [*sic; should be 22:16*] : 'I am - the bright and morning star.'

Comment: This is quite interesting to read. Thanks.

Comment: Mod piping in, I think this is very relevant to Bible study. It borders on Theology, but there is much to be asked about the Bible relating to this larger curiosity many share. Cheers all for keeping it focused on Hermeneutics!